# Google +1 Count for my homepage not for all subpages?

Tags: javascript, plugins, google-plus-one

I implemented the fairly new Google +1 Button to a site I've developed. It sits in my footer and I want people to just +1 this page if the think it's a cool page. Since I implemented it already a few people clicked it on the homepage.

However when clicking a link to a subsite of my page or the URL has an e.g., a #hash in it the +1 Button in my footer looses his count and start again with zero. Of course that's the purpose of the +1 Button to "like" or "+1" each article and each page on a website.

I wonder if it's possible to have the same global count of the button on my entire website?

Comment: Which code did you use to implement the +1 button? Is the href attribute set?

Comment: i simply used what google gave me: `<g:plusone size="medium"></g:plusone>`

Comment: I added an possible answer. Not sure if it will work. We had an plusone problem similar to this earlier this week. And adding an href attribute solved it. Only we're using variable values for the attribute instead of and hardcoded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could try to do is use the href attribute in the plusone tag. Like this;

```
<g:plusone size="medium" href="http://www.mydomain.com"></g:plusone>
```

This way you can force an url into the plusone. Just a long shot, not sure if it will work. More about the href attribute is explained [here](http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/adding-new-google-plus-one-1-button-your-drupal-site).